# Adjusting and positioning divs inside container

Tags: html, css

I have following markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-rect"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ispum</div>
    <div class="right-rect"></div>
</div>

.left-rect,
.right-rect { 
    background-color: #EEE;
    width: 9px;
}
.container {
    background-color: #555;
    height: 20px;
}
```

I want it to looks like: [image: example]

And, what is important: .rect's width have to depend on .text width, which is automatically adjusting to size of its content. 
So, if I'll put longer text into .text, the .rect should be wider, and left and right rects shoud be still on the edges. The .rect div can be placed anywhere (by js).
And I've got completely no idea how to do it.
I hope you'll understand what i wrote.

Comment: Where you have used .rect in your code, Please correct it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hPy5D/ like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` for `div`

**CSS**:

```
.rect { 
    background-color: #EEE;
    width: 9px;
    height: 13px;
}

.container {
    background-color: #555;
    width: 165px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
}

.rect, .text {
    display: inline-block;
}

.text {
    color: #EEE;
    margin: 0 30px;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vule/HE8h8/)**

Comment: I can't figure out why that solution doesn't work here http://jsfiddle.net/FSMMA/2/

Comment: @Kiro tat is because you have fixed the width as 100px. Make it as min-width:100px; and add width:auto as well. If there is no real requirement of 100px width, then you can remove width property completely.  Check here http://jsfiddle.net/FSMMA/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` for div

**CSS**

```
.left-rect,
.right-rect { 
    background-color: white;
    width: 9px; 
    display:inline-block
}
.container {
    background-color: #555;
    height: 20px;
    padding:4px;
     display:inline-block;
    color:white
}
.text{
    display:inline-block
}
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u76A2/2/)**

You can try adding long text, it extends based on the text length.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily

**write this css**

```
.left-rect{
float:left;
  margin-left:16px;
}
.right-rect{
float:right;
  margin-right:16px;
}
.left-rect,
.right-rect { 
    background-color: #EEE;
    width: 9px;
  height:16px;
  margin-top:2px;
}
.container {
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px;
 }
```

**Write this html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-rect"></div>

    <div class="right-rect"></div>
   <div class="text">Lorem ispum</div>
</div>
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/adDZtIgu)***